# Want to get result by comparing maximum dates of operation between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my mysql code

```
SELECT ri.imei
     , ri.date
     , ti.date
 FROM returned_items ri     
  JOIN transfer_items ti  
    ON ri.imei = ti.imei
 WHERE MAX(ri.date) >= MAX(ti.date)
```

I have 2 tables named **returned_items** and **transfer_items**.

There are multiple transfers and returns for an IMEI.

I want to check if the latest/max returned_items date for an IMEI is greater than latest/max transfer_items date or not.

But this code generates error **#1111 - Invalid use of group function**.

Please suggest me a way I can get the result.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `group by` clause, you can also use `having by` instead of `where`

```
select ri.imei, ri.date, ti.date
from returned_items ri
join transfer_items ti on ti.imei = ri.imei
group by ri.imei
having max(ri.date) > max(ti.date)
```

Comment: Note: This is only valid if `imei` be a primary or unique key.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, OP didn't specify table schema or sample data, so lets assume this is primary key, we just want to address the error he encountered.

Comment: Let's instead ask the OP to clarify. That way, the question becomes useful for others with a similar problem

Comment: @IRasel . . . I understand the upvotes on this question, but this really is not the best way to answer this question.  First, the query is not syntactically correct.  Second, it is probably too  expensive.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . There is no need to clarify.  The OP clearly says that there are multiple rows, so `imei` cannot be the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You should aggregate *before* joining.  This is important for performance reasons.  In your case, it doesn't affect the results, but it would in other cases:

```
select ri.imei, ri.ri_date, ti.ti_date
from (select ri.imei, max(ri.date) as ri_date
      from returned_items ri
      group by ri.imei
     ) ri join
     (select ti.imei, max(ti.date) as ti_date
      from transfer_items ti
      group by ti.imei
     ) ti
     on ti.imei = ri.imei
having ri.ri_date > ti.ti_date;
```